# Django Tutorial Step 2

Tags: django, database, models

I am at the shell part of the django tutorial I added the ____str____ method to the polls/models.py

here is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
```

However when I run my server I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
polls.Choice.question: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model    'Question', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Can someone show where I goofed up my models.py I cant find a completed example for that tutorial.

Comment: Why do you have the class `Question` defined two times?

Comment: oh so Im just supposed to put that second def there?

I will try that, that tutorial is a bit hard to figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have two model classes named **Question** delete the second one and move the function into the first **Question** class.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was published_recently(self):
        ##
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created 2 models with name **Question**. So please remove the second one.It creates a collision thst's why the Choice class can't find the **Question** Model.